# Is argument or parameter considered more appropriate for a function/method argument/parameter?

Tags: semantics

Hopefully the topic is not too confusing, I am curious though as lately I have seen more and more use of the word parameter to denote a function's passed in values, whereas during my studies I feel as if argument was used almost exclusively.

Is parameter more appropriate as argument is more specific to a programs arguments specific at runtime whereas when a function is called, the values passed to it are parameters to the function itself?

From a curious programmer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See t[his article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_science%29#Parameters_and_arguments) in wikipedia with a good explanation.
The difference is that parameters appear in method/function definitions, while arguments are concrete values you pass to a method/function.

Comment: Thanks, answers my question and actually does make sense.  A function has parameters, a function is called with arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Given a function defined like:

```
int f(int y) { /* ... */ }
```

and a call like:

```
int a = 3;
f(a);
```

`y` is the parameter (aka "formal parameter"), and `a` is the argument.

Answer (score 6):

I found this definition very simple to explain:

- a *parameter* is a "hole" in your function definition
- an *argument* is what the client uses to fill that "hole"

Answer (score 0):

In college, I was taught that the correct term is "argument".  I think either are appropriate and both definitions are obvious to most developers, but, from a technical standpoint, I generally stick with "argument".