# Can Attribute and Property, Method and Function be used inter-changeably in Software world?

Tags: terminology, software, keywords

Some pairs like these:

1. Method and Function
2. Attribute and Property
3. Argument and Parmameter

etc. 
I use all the three pairs interchangeably when I speak to a peer. Do they have a very critical difference or are language specific?

I have found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments) and  [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/is-argument-or-parameter-considered-more-appropriate-for-a-function-method-argum) on the 3rd pair, both suggests that they are used interchangeably in most cases.

Please let me know your thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/155609

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/258469

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, this site does not show stackoverflow's QnAs as suggestions..

Comment: A parameter is the declaration you make in the method's definition.  An argument is the value that is passed to it when you call the method.  From the Wikipedia article you linked: *"The term parameter (sometimes called formal parameter) is often used to refer to the variable as found in the function definition, while argument (sometimes called actual parameter) refers to the actual input supplied at function call."*

Comment: I understand your answer, but are they strictly distinguished by this difference across the world? if not? why is there any debate around this I see on internet.

Comment: Because it is the internet.  For your purposes, you can consider this the one true definition.

Comment: it also states:
"The terms parameter and argument may have different meanings in different programming languages. Sometimes they are used interchangeably, and the context is used to distinguish the meaning"

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that.  Since Wikipedia doesn't give specifics, there isn't anything you can do with that information anyway.  The definition I gave you is well-understood by most software developers.

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but in my experience, no. These terms have meanings in certain contexts and are not equivalent, even if they are conceptually very similar. @RobertHarvey's description of parameter vs argument is a prime example. That being said, most mature software developers who understand the difference will understand your meaning.

Comment: Consider asking this question on the [English Language and Usage Stack](https://english.stackexchange.com/)